# Driving 3-4v laser from 5v arduino

Tags: arduino, laser

I want to control the following laser module from an arduino digital output:

- Specification V2 – Aug 2010
- Wavelength : 650nm +/-5nm
- Output Power : 4-5mW
- Operating Voltage: V2 = 3.0-4.0V
- Operating Current:    15-20mA
- Operating Temperature: 10 – 40°C

What's the best approach - I've looked at diodes for voltage drops, resistors and regulators but I really don't know which to use.  The variability of the voltage and current in the specs is rather confusing.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a dedicated laser driver IC such as the [iC-WKL](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/laser-module/6973547/) from Global Laser.
This will take care of the careful regulation needed. It expects a laser diode with an inbuilt  monitor diode for optical regulation.

Other less ideal ways to drive them are:

- A series resistor to limit current as you would with a normal LED - some more robust modern diodes can apparently be used like this quite successfully.
- A constant current setup.

Laser diodes are usually very sensitive to variations in current/voltage (the lasing threshold is quite close to the maximum threshold so not a lot of room for error) so check your datasheet to see how much "play" you have.

[This page](http://www.repairfaq.org/sam/laserdps.htm) has some good info on laser diodes.

Comment: It's a module with a current regulator built in, not just a diode. Given this, would a series resistor be ok? According to my maths the resistor will be between 50-133R, seems like quite a large range to me.

Comment: @JimmyP - Can you link to the datasheet?

Comment: Couldn't find a data sheet, only what was provided above.  I've treated it like an LED and added a series resistor, hooked the meter into it and everything's working as expected.  Cheers.